# Why does installing `googletrans` to a `flask_socketio` app give `Invalid async_mode specified`

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio, googletrans

When I install `googletrans` into the most barebones `flask_socketio` server, running the server gives me `Invalid async_mode specified`.

Here is the basic Flask app:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app=app, cors_allowed_origins="*")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=3001)
```

It uses this Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
flask="*"
flask-socketio = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.11"
```

`pipenv install` and `pipenv run python app.py` works fine.

## How it Breaks

But, if you `pipenv install googletrans` and `pipenv run python app.py`, it breaks:

### Broken Pipfile

```
[packages]
flask="*"
flask-socketio = "*"
googletrans="*"
```

### Response

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\git\flask-socket-test\app.py", line 5, in <module>
    socketio = SocketIO(app=app, cors_allowed_origins="*")
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\flask-socket-test-RBuOQeqq\Lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 187, in __init__
    self.init_app(app, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\flask-socket-test-RBuOQeqq\Lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 243, in init_app
    self.server = socketio.Server(**self.server_options)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\flask-socket-test-RBuOQeqq\Lib\site-packages\socketio\base_server.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.eio = self._engineio_server_class()(**engineio_options)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\flask-socket-test-RBuOQeqq\Lib\site-packages\engineio\base_server.py", line 81, in __init__
    raise ValueError('Invalid async_mode specified')
ValueError: Invalid async_mode specified
```

## Is it `googletrans` or its dependencies?

I looked at what packages `googletrans` depends on, to see if it was its dependencies or google translate itself.

I froze the requirements of the failing google translate build, removed google translate, and I was left with this pipfile:

```
[packages]
flask="*"
flask-socketio = "*"
certifi="*"
chardet="*"
h2="*"
hpack="*"
hstspreload="*"
httpcore="*"
httpx="*"
hyperframe="*"
idna="*"
rfc3986="*"
anyio="*"
sniffio="*"
```

I `pipenv uninstall -all`'d, installed this, ran it, and it did not throw the anync error therefore **the issue is in the googletrans package itself**.